# Can you replace dash in metric name with underscore?

Tags: prometheus

I am scraping an exporter that gives me metric names with dashes.  Prometheus metric names cannot have dashes so I fail to scrape those metrics.

Is it possible to replace the dash with an underscore to make the metric name valid?

- Current: `collectd_a-b_derive_total`.
- Desired: `collectd_a_b_derive_total`.

I added this to my config but it does not appear to work.

```
      - source_labels: [__name__]
        regex: "(.*)-(.*)"
        action: replace
        target_label: "${1}_${2}"
```

Also, what is a good way to debug this?

Answer (score 3):

You were really close, in case someone interested in te answer it would be

```
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    regex: "(.*)-(.*)"
    action: replace
    replacement: "${1}_${2}"
    target_label: "__name__"
```

this should do the work.

Comment: can someone exlpain why "$1_$2" is not valid (not works)?

Answer (score 0):

I emailed the prometheus-users mailing list and someone responded that Prometheus cannot "fix" metric names with dashes/hyphens.

Since, I prefer to not edit the application emitting the metrics, I found a workaround.

1. Set up Nginx.
2. Configure it as a reverse proxy.

   - Listen on 19103.
   - Get and rewrite body from 9103 using Nginx's sub_filter directive.
3. Configure Prometheus to scrape 19103 instead of 9103.

Sample reverse-proxy.conf:

```
server{
  listen 19103;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9103;
    sub_filter_types *;
    sub_filter 'purple-' 'purple_';
    sub_filter_once off;
  }
}
```